# How can I order when using pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

This might be quite simple question.

Here's my code. Then I want to sort `@codes` ordered by the column `code.user.last_active_at`

```
#here, I retrieve only the records that contains particular keyword.
@search = Code.search do  
    fulltext params[:search]
    with(:community_id, community_search)
    paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 1000000
end  

#Here, I try pagination. 10 records per each page.  
@codes = @search.results
@codes = Kaminari.paginate_array(@codes).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

I want to sort them ordered by the column `@code.user.last_active_at`
How can I do that?

I tried this

```
@codes = Kaminari.paginate_array(@codes.joins(:user).order('user.last_active_at DESC')).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

But it returned this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `joins' for #
<Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollection:0x0000001ca851a8>):
app/controllers/codes_controller.rb:95:in `index'
```

How can I sort while I'm using `Kaminari pagination`?

Answer (score 1):

Kaminari not affect on sorting. first you have to sort and then get page(x).per(x)
so for example in your controller

```
@codes = @search.results
@codes = @codes.joins(:user).order('user.last_active_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

edit:
after check sunspot documentation I think you can make something like

```
@search = Code.search(include: :user) do  
    fulltext params[:search]
    with(:community_id, community_search)
    order_by('user.last_active_at DESC')
    #paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10 you can add this and not use Kaminari
end
```

you can try joins except include

Comment: Thanks!!!! I tried your code but it returned this :(  `NoMethodError (undefined method `joins' for #<Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollection:0x00000016a4b7b0>):
  app/controllers/codes_controller.rb:95:in `index'
`

Comment: This is one of the reason why I was using Kaminari for pagination.

Comment: so problem isn't in Kaminari but in search. I don't know sunspot but Whay you add "paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 1000000. remove it and try

Comment: `"paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 1000000"` is not related to pagination. That handles the maximum number of result records. So I f I state it `"paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 30"` It only retrieves 30 records even if there are more than 100 records result hit! and 10 records per each page. SO in that case, it only will have 3 page for result.

Comment: this "Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollection" tell us about return PaginatedCollection. Like I check in suspot you can remove it... limit 1000000 it's a lot.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your new update but now it returns this `NameError (wrong constant name User.lastActiveAt descSort):`

Comment: if you code with this format, how can you customize???? `order_by :user_last_active_at, :desc` I noticed that your format didn't work before!!

Comment: Isn't it something like `order_by :user => {:last_active_at, :desc}`?